# Wasm specifcation clearification

Tags: compiler-construction, webassembly

I'm currently writing a toy compiler from frontend to backend targeting wasm. I know a bit of x86 and mips, but more or less at the point where I can write small portion of code, and read others code.

I have a clarifying question about the *'labels'*. In the specification, it ways that the labeling are relative to the point of execution/nesting. This lead me to two questions about how to use branching/jumps.

1. Loops:

   Say we have some while loop where there is a nesting of *l* labels where *l >= 0*. Would the code below be right? (the code is represented in a abstract tree not the correct format of wat, the block types are not included, but assume implicit pushing and popping to and from the stack)

   ```
    block(
        loop( 
            // compute condition value
            if(  
                //  compute the effect of the loop
            )
            else( // if false then break the loop
               br(l + 2) 
            )
        )
    )
   ```
2. Jump tables:

   If the above is true, how does this affect forward jumping?
   say we want to compile a switch statement with subject s tested against *c* cases. How would this be expressed in wasm? I know each case should be a block, it is more the labeling.

I know that I most likely have overthink this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I believe you would just want `br 2` (`br 0` would break out of the if and `br 1` would break out of the loop and `br 2` breaks out of the block).  From the docs [at](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/instructions.html#):

   > label 0 refers to the innermost structured control instruction enclosing the referring branch instruction, while increasing indices refer to those farther out.

2. I believe you can use `br_table` instruction for this (may depend on how sparse the enum cases are).

Comment: I was a little more clear headed today. I found this https://gist.github.com/dschuff/f0f4c7d3a1f09001e83a33cc9a20aebd That supports your way. It is just a bit different than MIPS and x86